# How to run a function that added to onsubmit attribute by jquery attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a page, and I want to do something when form submitted; This is the form:

```
<form class="tsf" action="/search" style="overflow:visible" id="tsf" method="GET" name="f" onsubmit="return q.value!=''" role="search">
```

I just wrote this code to add a new function before `return q.value!=''`

```
$("#tsf").attr('onsubmit', "do_something(); return q.value!=''");
```

And I defined do_something after that:

```
function do_something(){
   alert("success");
}
```

But console return an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: do_something is not defined

**How can I call and run this function (do_something) using this way?**

**Note:** *For some reasons, I'm only able to add my function to onsubmit and I am just looking for a way to run `do_something()` in this way!*

Comment: can you share a fiddle to show this error?

Comment: you cant do it the other way around like adding click event handler?

Comment: @guradio No, because it is sending Ajax request and the only way I found is add the function to onsubmit and when form submitted, run what I want

Comment: you can have `$('#tsf').submit()` to submit form

Comment: A fiddle reproducing your issue. https://jsfiddle.net/7toahqo2/

Comment: check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/qwu5as1o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can set it off first and then create a new handler

```
function do_something(){
   alert("success");
}
function attachNewMethod()
{
  $('#tsf').prop('onclick',null).off('click');
  $("#tsf").attr('onsubmit', "do_something(); return q.value!=''");
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7toahqo2/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work! What about event listeners?

Comment: Did you checked the fiddle?

Comment: Yes; but not worked in my code. You know that form is Google form and input is its search field. I'm developing a chrome extension and I need to send Google search term to server

Comment: In that case you need to share the fiddle of your attempt